# Problem with multiple stores on PWA solution/Upward connector when I have multiple Web Site with the same domain

Tags: magento2, pwa, upward-connector

I am working on Magento solution with multiple stores with structure as you can see on image.
When I have different domain everything works fine, but when I have same domain on different Web Site - PWA solution return empty page. Is it possible create this structure on PWA/Magento with Upward connector?

[image]

Comment: Hello, Any solution?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you find a solution? Could you shed a light on this? :)

Comment: Hello, I didn't find solution and after that I changed structure of stores for my store